# Help in finding real irreducible representation of $Q_8$

Tags: representation-theory

I have the following facts that I don't know how to prove:

i) $\mathbb{R}[Q_8] = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{H} $

where $\mathbb{H}$ is $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of dimension 4, quaternion algebra.

ii) these are the 1 dimensional representation that I think are the only possibiities

$1 \mapsto 1, -1 \mapsto 1$

and $i \mapsto \pm 1, j \mapsto \pm 1$ gives us four different 1 dimension representation.

Is this true, and if this is true, then how do we prove that those representations are irreducible? I would use inner products of characters if the field was algebraically closed, but obviously, $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed.

Thank you!

Comment: 1-dimensional representations are always irreducible simply for lack of non-trivial subspaces.